# Add 1 to an element inside a list and return a different list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, genetic-algorithm

I wrote the following code:

```
population = [[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1], [0]],
 [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [3], [1]],
 [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [4], [2]],
 [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [3], [3]]]

def ManipulateFitness(population):
    mf=[]
    populaion_m = population
    for game in range (0, len(population)):
        m = [f+1 for f in population[game][1]]
        mf.append(m)
        manipulted = [m for f in population[game][1] for m in mf
        population_m.append(manipulated)
    return (population_m)
```

What I am trying to do is just adding a 1 to the second element in the list (the third is just a counter)for each chromosome and return the same list with just this different values, but with a different name, since Ill need both later on. I was trying it like this but it didnt work, I managed to generate the values but I wasnt successfull in adding them to the list in the correct places. Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. The second element in the list is `[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [3], [1]]`, you can't add 1 to that. Define "add 1". 2. "It didn't work" is not an acceptable error description.

Comment: You haven't given the error you face. For one, you have a typo; you have `population_m` and `populaion_m`. `populaion_m = population` (sic) doesn't create a copy of `population`, it just creates another name for the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that you want to add an additional element `1` to the second item of each list:

```
population = [[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1], [0]], [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [3], [1]], [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [4], [2]], [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [3], [3]]]
new_population = [[b+[1] if i == 1 else b for i, b in enumerate(a)] for a in population]
```

Output:

```
[[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1], [0]], [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [3, 1], [1]], [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [4, 1], [2]], [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [3, 1], [3]]]
```

However, if you merely wish to increment the element in the second list, you can try this:

```
new_population = [[[b[0]+1] if i == 1 else b for i, b in enumerate(a)] for a in population]
```

Output:

```
[[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [2], [0]], [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [4], [1]], [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [5], [2]], [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [4], [3]]]
```